# Updating a value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I aam trying to update one value in rails which is in sidekiq worker. But for first time whenever i restart the worker it works but after it doesn't update the value. I tried putting that thing into model also and calling that method from worker itself but same thing happened.

```
def update_value
   self.update :compressing => false
end

name.update_value
```

OR

```
name.update_attribute(:compressing, 0)
```

OR

```
name.update_attribute(:compressing, false)
```

nothing seems to work after first time, but no error. Any hint will be really helpful.

Comment: Please paste your `name` object.

Comment: You can also use update_attributes with `!` operator this will throw an error if any validation get failed e.g. `name.update_attributes!(compressing: 0)`

Comment: Its not printing anything :/ and it didn't even change.

Comment: please check the sidekiq log i think you will find the error there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a controller? You need to get the name instance first e.g.

```
def update_value
  @name = Name.find(params[:id])
  @name.update_attributes(compressing: false)
end
```

Comment: i already have that name instance. Some issue is with update thing i guess. And its in Background Worker.

Comment: It doesn't say anything i tried update_attributes! to get errors but no error came.

Comment: is it worth adding some more logging into the controller to see what the name instance looks like?

Comment: I got it working. The issue was for some weird reasons it was losing my name object.